# wicd tray icon not visible on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: networking, 20.04, wicd

I saw this issue reported and resolved for past versions. WICD is not built for 20.04 yet I believe. I downloaded the version 19 package and set it up for 20.04 as suggested on some thread. I can run the wicd-client as well, however there is no tray icon visible. A resolution for this problem for prior versions suggested installing dconf-tools. This package is not available for 20.04.
Apologies if this was answered elsewhere. I could not locate it though, hence the question. All help is appreciated (I am relatively new to Linux too).